# how to make a div disappear if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make an input disappear if javascript is disabled, i have tried,

```
<script>
document.getelementbyid('mydiv').innerhtml= <input type=text>;
</script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

so that if javascript is disabled the code will not put the input in the div
but in my browser console it says document.getelementbyid('myinput') is undefined, but if i put in a function  my browser console doesn't say anything is there a way i can make a function run immediately the page is loaded or to make the input show only when javascript is enabled

Comment: Just place the script after the element, and correct the spelling of the properties.

Comment: _“but in my browser console it says document.getelementbyid('myinput') is undefined”_ - because the element did not exist already at that point, where you tried to access it here. Change the order, so that the `script` element comes _after_ the element you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanna do this. Notice the spell corrections:

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML= '<input type=text>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so `getelementbyid` is not the same as `getElementById`.

The correct function is `document.getElementById`.

The same problem with `innerhtml`. It should be `innerHTML`.

Also `<input type=text>` should be in quotes, because it is a string.

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML= '<input type="text">';
</script>
```